# Extjs dynamically loaded html/javascript gives an error

Tags: javascript, extjs

I load a grid panel and associated html dynamically in my application. When it is loaded for the second time it gives an error like this.

Uncaught Error: DOM element with id category-editor-grid1 in Element cache is not the same as element in the DOM. Make sure to clean up Element instances using destroy()

Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: Please post some code or a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove it from the cache

```
if(Ext.Element.cache.hasOwnProperty(domId)){
    Ext.Element.cache[domId].destroy();
}
```

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?286213-Ext-get()-throws-errors-if-the-element-has-the-same-id-as-a-recently-removed-element/

Answer (score 0):

The point is what you do with the first instance of the grid. You have to remove it using the function destroy().

Since you use the id property, your panel must be unique throughout the lifetime of your application. If you need two instances at the same time, you could use the itemId property to reference the panel in your code instead.